# Which factors determine callback frequency in requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, gpu

As I understand different browsers use a different implementation of requestAnimationFrame.

I need to know which factors (Hardware/Software) affect the callback frequency, specifically how is the GPU involved?

Is the implementation specification mentioned somewhere?

(I found in the following link that it definitely should have some affect:

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/09/23/cross-browser-gpu-acceleration-and-requestanimationframe-in-depth/

"What does GPU acceleration have to do with requestAnimationFrame? Most of the time, if GPU acceleration is active in a browser, it means that requestAnimationFrame callbacks happen a lot more frequently" )

Thanks.